# Access expression, add one year, minus a day

Tags: ms-access, expression, dateadd

I have a table in access, which has a contract start date, contract end date.

It also needs auto filled columns for the start and end date of each year between the contract start and end dates.

E.g, customer takes out 5 year contract.

01/01/2020 - 01/01/2025

Year 1’s end date would be 1 year, minus a day from the contract start date:

31/12/2020.

As mentioned, this needs to be written as an expression in Microsoft Access.

I can’t find info on multiple date calculations from a singular start date (DateAdd etc).

Thanks for any help

Comment: DateAdd() is not available for Calculated Field in table. Really no need to save in table. Do calculations in query or textboxes. Otherwise, use VBA to populate table fields. What do you mean by 'multiple date calculations from a singular start date' - calculate as many fields as needed.

Comment: Hi, thank you, this was what I suspected, essentially, contracts from customers can vary in length (the range is usually between 1 - 5 years), There's a start date and end date, of which the payment dates are one year, minus a day from start date - then the following day leads into the next year of their contract (so on and so forth etc).

I was aiming to have the database formulate the payment dates on the table, rather than query, however, it looks as though query is the way forward.

Thanks again for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DateAdd in code (or query):

```
UltimoYear = DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("yyyy", 5, DateStart))
```

Replace 5 with 1 for one year.

Comment: Or `DateAdd("yyyy", 5, DateStart) - 1` because day unit is default for date arithmetic.

Comment: Hi Gustav, thank you for your reply, I was aware of the -1 ability for the DateAdd function, however, it wouldn't accept this in the calculated field for a table setup. Looks as though query is the only way to pull this info.